# nvimの設定（init.vim）で構文エラーが出ますが、何が悪いのかわかりません。

Tags: bash, vim, neovim

基本的なことだと思うのですが、nvimのinit.vimについて、下記内容のエラーを消せません。

```
let g:python3_host_prog = system('(type pyenv &>/dev/null && echo -n "$(pyenv 
root)/versions/$(pyenv global | grep python3)/bin/python") || echo -n $(which 
python3)')
```

何が悪いのでしょう？
エラー内容は下記です。

```
init.vim: 行 2: 予期しないトークン `(' 周辺に構文エラーがあります
init.vim: 行 2: `let g:python3_host_prog = system('(type pyenv &>/dev/null &&         
echo -n "$(pyenv root)/versions/$(pyenv global | grep python3)/bin/python") 
|| echo -n $(which python3)')'
```

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

> let g:python3_host_prog = system('(type pyenv &>/dev/null && echo -n "$(pyenv 
>   root)/versions/$(pyenv global | grep python3)/bin/python") || echo -n $(which 
>   python3)')

上記コードは1行ですか？
複数行の場合はエラーになりますが…

Comment: 構文からすると合ってるように見えるので、周りのコードも載せて貰えないでしょうか。

Comment: お早い回答いただいていたのに返信が遅れすみません。
コメントを受けて他を確認したところ、上記箇所以外にミスがありました。アドバイスありがとうございました。